# Fitting a Gaussian function to Poisson noisy data

Tags: regression, regularization, overfitting, curve-fitting, inverse-problem

Let $A$, $\mu$, $\sigma$ be some positive, a priori unknown parameters. Define a Gaussian function $f$ as
$$f(x) = A \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right).$$

One measures noisy values of $f$ at grid points $x_j = j/N$, where $j = 0, 1, \dots, N$. Let $y_j$ denote the measured value of $f$ at $x_j$. The task is to estimate the parameters $A$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the measurements.

For each $j = 0, 1, \dots, N$, $y_j$ is a realization of the random variable $Y_j \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(f(x_j))$. Therefore, the level of noise is different for each $y_j$ and depends on the unknown value of $f(x_j)$. Many regularization methods that I have encountered assume that the noise is white noise from $N(0, \sigma^2)$ with some a priori known variance $\sigma^2$ and thus, the level of noise is known. I don't know how to approach this problem to avoid overfitting.

Here's an example. I have chosen $A = 10$, $\mu = 1/2$, $\sigma = 1/10$ and $N = 29$. The figure below illustrates the noisy measurements (blue) and the Gaussian function $f$ (red). Observe that the grid is quite sparse.
[image]

I fitted a Gaussian function using least squares. The result is shown below with the exact Gaussian curve; the grid is now finer for visualization purposes.

[image]

We observe that the result is not at all satisfactory. Of course, the noisy data was quite unfortunate as it had really high values when compared to the expected value.

One may improve the results by using a finer grid and/or gathering multiple samples. However, this is not feasible in all real-world applications.

What kind of regularization techniques could I use to avoid overfitting with this kind of Poisson data? One could use, e.g., ridge regression, but the choice of the regularization parameter becomes a challenge. Or does one simply need more data points to "average" the noise to zero?

Comment: You don't need regularization.  What you need is an appropriate fitting procedure.  The ones most often used for this problem are (a) weighted least squares (as an approximation, but generally a good one) and (b) maximum likelihood.  It's unclear why the fit is "not at all satisfactory." (I have a lot of experience with this particular problem and I don't see anything problematic here.  Indeed, a more accurate fit will be similar to the red curve but a bit *lower* at the peak.) When your eye disagrees with the fit, you should *test the goodness of fit* to make sure you're not fooling yourself.

Comment: An additional point is that there is no question of "overfitting" here, because your model is well specified and parsimonious.  It's hard to describe a curve having arbitrary position, width, and height with fewer than three parameters and no other "nuisance" parameters are involved for describing the conditional distributions.